# summation of random variable into harmonic number

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers

In our textbook "Algorithm Design" we are given an example of a deck of $n$ cards and we have to guess the correct card, and every time a card is drawn, we remember that cards so we are uniformally guessing only among the  cards not yet seen.
I don't understand the final part of the following summation, where the authors reduce the summation to a harmonic number... note: the random variable $X_i$ takes on 1 if the ith value is correct or 0 otherwise:
$$\Pr[X] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n E[X_i] = \sum\limits_{i=1} ^n \frac {1}{n-i+1} = \sum\limits_{i =1}^n \frac {1}{i}$$
I don't see how they derived $\sum\limits_{i =1}^n \frac {1}{i}$, which I know becomes a harmonic number [Ideally someone might show this without calculus]...
Thanks

Comment: I think what you have written is incorrect... It should be $\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}i$, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They reindexed the sum. As $i$ runs from $1$ to $n$, $j=n-i+1$ runs from $n$ to $1$, so

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{n-i+1}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1j=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i\;.
$$